# Google Sheets - Array Formula that searches each row and returns a cell value based on conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

My data contains traffic source data from Google Analytics, grouped by customer. For each row, there is a `TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(` function that fills a horizontal array of values from another sheet. Any customers in the source sheet that have multiple rows with different values for traffic source will have an array of two or more values.

[image]

The formula I need is in column B. The formula I have so far is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="",C2:C,IF(COUNTIF($C:$Z,"Affiliate")>0,"Affiliate","-")))
```

The required output is an array that returns a value of source based on the condition set in the COUNTIF part of the formula. In this case I want "Affiliate" to be returned if it is present in the corresponding row. If it is not present, but "Referral" is present, return "Referral", otherwise return "-". Currently the formula returns "Affiliate" if it is present anywhere in the $C:$Z array, and is therefore not row-based.

Is there a way to change the array formula to search each row independently and return values based on the defined conditions?

[Link to sample data with desired output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uIQFaJlEMExwgqxl-p9oznEUtpqlI70gXLLAV4uIytg/edit?usp=sharing)

Edit: included link to sample data with required output. Also changed required output to include multiple values:

*In this case I want "Affiliate" to be returned if it is present in the corresponding row. If it is not present, but "Referral" is present, return "Referral", otherwise return "-". Currently the formula returns "Affiliate" if it is present anywhere in the $C:$Z array, and is therefore not row-based.*

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/169458/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data side-by-side your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `byrow()`, `join()` and `match()`, like this:

```
=byrow( 
  C2:Z, 
  lambda( 
    row, 
    ifs( 
      len(join("", row)) = 0, iferror(1/0), 
      ifna(match("Affiliate", row, 0)), "Affiliate", 
      ifna(match("Referral", row, 0)), "Referral", 
      true, "-" 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The results look like this:

| Customer | Attribution | Source array |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dweezil | Affiliate | Affiliate | d | e | f | g |
| Moon Unit | - | c | d | e | f | g |
| Ziggy | Affiliate | c | d | e | Affiliate | g |

See [byrow()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930), [join()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094077) and [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly. I wonder - I've just edited the question to include multiple values. How would that affect the formula? Sample data also linked in the question

Comment: Edited the answer per your new requirements. Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: Thanks - my bad I'm new to this!